# Cannot execute external vb script from Java program through Jenkins Slave setup

Tags: java, vbscript, jenkins

Through Jenkins - Slave setup (running in Windows), we have created a ANT job which in internally calls the below JAVA Program,

```
String[] command = {"cmd" , "/c", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Read_email/ReadEmail.vbs"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
System.out.println("Process Completed");
```

The `ReadEmail.vbs` file never gets called or executed.
There is no error message or warning getting generated.

When I run this java program from eclipse or through Master Jenkinks, VB Scripts gets executed without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
String[] command = {"cmd" , "/c", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Read_email/ReadEmail.vbs"};
```

relies on the executing process to know where to find cmd.exe and who to call for a .vbs.

I used a 'fully redundant':

```
String[] command = {"C:/WINDOWS/system32/cmd.exe" , "/c", "C:/WINDOWS/system32/cscript.exe", "E:/trials/SoTrials/answers/21228622/java/callme.vbs"};
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.format("%s\n", e.toString());
}
```

successfully from a simple commandline program. I hope this strategy works for your more complicated Jenkins setup.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this issue. I tried giving absolute path but still facing the same issue.