# Running a VBS file from java -- no result no error

Tags: java, vb.net

I have a vbs file which do some validation and I would like to run it from java. I have followed the standard code to run, but no results coming out , even the no exception is thrown by eclipse. When I run the vbs file alone, it runs perfectly fine. I don't know what I am missing if don't see any exception. My code is like that:

```
String strVBpath  = "C:\\Users\\Nur\\Documents\\tr.vbs";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript " + strVBpath );
```

could you please let me know what possibly went wrong. by the way if I run another vbs file which contains only a msgbox "Hello World" ,, it runs good from java , but why my tr.vbs is not running.

Comment: What kind of validation its doing? Does it require any escalations? Try this - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21228622/cannot-execute-external-vb-script-from-java-program-through-jenkins-slave-setup

Answer (score 0):

No, its a straight forward code, the code read some file and write the results back to Excel. I was trying to run it from eclipse. No error   no results.